# CreateDirectoryAtPath: doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have simple code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (!fileManager) NSLog(@"Manager doesn't exist!");

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destString]) {
    if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:destString withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }
}
else NSLog(@"Exists!");
```

vars:

```
destString = file://localhost/Users/SOMEUSER/Desktop/NEWFOLDER/
```

When I am trying to create a folder then program writes "Exists" but on desktop doesn't exist. When I remove fileExistsAtPath: then there's no error but no directory too. Thx 4 reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` takes the path to create as a UNIX-style path string, and not as a file URL-style string. That is, you want to pass it a string like `/Users/SOMEUSER/Desktop/NEWFOLDER/`.

Alternatively, if you're dealing with a URL-style string then you could switch to using `-createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` instead and construct an `NSURL` from your string.